# React Formik checkbox group does not turn into an array of invidual checked or unchecked elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I am using Formik to create a form on a website. In this form I have a set of tags which I want to be checkable with individual checkboxes, but keep them in an array `tags`. Formik claims to be able to do so by using the same `name` attribute on the Field elements, but I can not get it to work.

I am using this [code example](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/blob/master/examples/Checkbox.js) as an reference.

Here is my code:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Formik, Form, Field } from "formik";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <ProjectsForm />
    </div>
  );
}

const ProjectsForm = props => (
  <Formik
    initialValues={{
      search: "",
      tags: []
    }}
    onSubmit={values => {
      console.log(values);
    }}
    validate={values => {
      console.log(values);
    }}
    validateOnChange={true}
  >
    {({ isSubmitting, getFieldProps, handleChange, handleBlur, values }) => (
      <Form>
        <Field type="text" name="search" />
        <label>
          <Field type="checkbox" name="tags" value="one" />
          One
        </label>
        <label>
          <Field type="checkbox" name="tags" value="two" />
          Two
        </label>
        <label>
          <Field type="checkbox" name="tags" value="three" />
          Three
        </label>
      </Form>
    )}
  </Formik>
);

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Also on [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-frog-4u8w1)

I am expecting to receive thought the `console.log(values)` to display something like:

`Object {search: "", tags: ['one', 'three']}`

or

`Object {search: "", tags: ['one': true, 'two': false, 'three': true]}`

Hope there is a simple thing I am missing to add the Formik checkbox group functionality, as it claims to be possible.

Answer (score 23):

It's pretty easy to accomplish using the `FieldArray` component.

Place your values in an array, something like this:

```js
const tagCollection = [
  { value: "one", label: "One" },
  { value: "two", label: "Two" },
  { value: "three", label: "Three" }
];
```

And then use the `FieldArray` like this:

```
<FieldArray
    name="tags"
    render={arrayHelpers => (
        <div>
            {tagCollection.map(tag => (
                <label key={tag.value}>
                    <input
                        name="tags"
                        type="checkbox"
                        value={tag}
                        checked={values.tags.includes(tag.value)}
                        onChange={e => {
                          if (e.target.checked) {
                            arrayHelpers.push(tag.value);
                          } else {
                            const idx = values.tags.indexOf(tag.value);
                            arrayHelpers.remove(idx);
                          }
                        }}
                    />
                    <span>{tag.label}</span>
                </label>
            ))}
        </div>
    )}
/>
```

[Working sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/quiet-mountain-y1s48)

---

Update:

You can also do this by writing your own component.

```js
const MyCheckbox = ({ field, form, label, ...rest }) => {
  const { name, value: formikValue } = field;
  const { setFieldValue } = form;

  const handleChange = event => {
    const values = formikValue || [];
    const index = values.indexOf(rest.value);
    if (index === -1) {
      values.push(rest.value);
    } else {
      values.splice(index, 1);
    }
    setFieldValue(name, values);
  };

  return (
    <label>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        onChange={handleChange}
        checked={formikValue.indexOf(rest.value) !== -1}
        {...rest}
      />
      <span>{label}</span>
    </label>
  );
};

// And using it like this:
<Field component={MyCheckbox} name="tags" value="one" label="One" />
<Field component={MyCheckbox} name="tags" value="two" label="Two" />
<Field component={MyCheckbox} name="tags" value="three" label="Three" />
```

Comment: Yes I found this also, but I was just wondering if there was something easier, as claimed by Formik in the example from GitHub.

Comment: Okay, I also added a different approach. Might be better/easier.

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly for me! Previously I tried to implement this like Formik's example but it never worked for me. Thanks for solving a huge headache!

Comment: @JapMul How can i handle validation for these group inputs ?

Answer (score 8):

With Formik 2 without any Formik specific components:

```
import React from "react";
import { useFormik } from "formik";

export default function App() {
  return <ProjectsForm></ProjectsForm>;
}

const tags = ["one", "two", "three"];

const ProjectsForm = () => {
  const formik = useFormik({
    enableReinitialize: true,
    initialValues: {
      tags: []
    },
    onSubmit: (values) => {
      console.log(values);
    }
  });

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { checked, name } = e.target;
    if (checked) {
      formik.setFieldValue("tags", [...formik.values.tags, name]);
    } else {
      formik.setFieldValue(
        "tags",
        formik.values.tags.filter((v) => v !== name)
      );
    }
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
      {tags.map((tag) => (
        <div key={tag}>
          <input
            id={tag}
            type="checkbox"
            name={tag}
            checked={formik.values.tags.includes(tag)}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
          <label htmlFor={tag}>{tag}</label>
        </div>
      ))}
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
};
```

I started by creating a simple array of tags.

Then I used `useFormik` hook to bind the form for an array of checkboxes. Whether a checkbox is checked, depends on whether it's in the tags array.
Hence: `formik.values.tags.includes(tag)`

I created a custom change handling function to set or remove a tag from Formik values depending on whether a checkbox is checked or not.

[Full working Sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/lively-wood-76uef?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Thank you for providing this. Formik 2 is quite different.